# Error FB is not defined Facebook login with Angular2 (CLI)

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular, facebook-graph-api, angular-cli

I want to use Facebook authentication as an Angular service. 
With this code I'm able to login/logout but when I login and refresh the page the variables *name* and *isUser* are also refreshed/reinitialized (as I understand due to Angular Life Cycle) - I try to *checkLoginState()* in ngOnInit to know if the user is still logged in and if he is I will query FB API and will reinitialize the values of the variables again. But the code fails because in ngOnInit FB is not defined yet. So what can be done to maintain the variable values unchanged after page refresh? Or should I save them globally or in cache? 
Thanks!

**FacebookService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class FacebookService {

  constructor() {
    if (!window.fbAsyncInit) {
      console.log('define');
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: "...youAppId...",
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.10'
        });
      };
    }
  }

  loadAndInitFBSDK(): Observable<any> {
    var js,
      id = 'facebook-jssdk',
      ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    if (document.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }

    js = document.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }


}
```

**AppComponent:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { FacebookService } from "app/Services/facebook.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app.component works!!!';
  name = "";
  isUser = false;

  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone, private _facebookService: FacebookService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._facebookService.loadAndInitFBSDK();
    /* if (this.checkLoginState()) { // Error in :0:0 caused by: FB is not defined
      this.setIsUser();
      this.setName();
    } */
  }


  login() {
    var self = this;
    FB.login(function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {

        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
          self._ngZone.run(() => {
            self.name = response.name;
            self.isUser = true
          });
        });

      } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    FB.logout(function (response) {
      location.reload();
    });
  }

  checkLoginState() {
    let isLoggedIn;
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        isLoggedIn = true;
      } else {
        isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });
    return isLoggedIn;
  }

  setName() {
    var self = this;
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
      self._ngZone.run(() => {
        self.name = response.name
      });
    });
  }

  setIsUser() {
    var self = this;
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
      self._ngZone.run(() => {
        self.isUser = true
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<div>
  <div *ngIf="!isUser" id="Login">

    <button (click)="login()">Log in with Facebook</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isUser" id="Logout">
    <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isUser">
  <h2> Welcome {{name}} </h2>
  </div>
<div *ngIf="!isUser">
  <p> Login please! </p>
  </div>


    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**AppModule:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './Components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MainComponent } from './Components/main/main.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponentComponent } from './Components/page-not-found-component/page-not-found-component.component';
import { FacebookService } from "app/Services/facebook.service";

const appRoutes: Routes = [


  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [] },
  { path: '', component: MainComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponentComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    MainComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [FacebookService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save them globally in your localStorage.

Here's a tutorial that shows how (not Facebook but the principles still apply):  http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: Trevor thx for respond. I've tried to do something similar as in the article. On login I execute localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", JSON.stringify(true));
and on logout  localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
But then if I do a page refresh and try to logout I'm getting **FB.logout() called without an access token.** error

Comment: Others have also had this issue, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234724/angular2-retain-sensitive-information-after-browser-refresh

Comment: It was very frustrating while I was trying to make it work by myself, I gave up and used a [Facebook SDK wrapper](https://github.com/zyra/ngx-facebook) it was easier to implement login/logout functionality but even there I experienced a similar problem - after page refresh I was getting **authResponse: null, status: "unknown"** on trying to **getLoginStatus()** and then I finally ran into a simple [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894683/4429157) to maintain logged in state after page refresh. I added **cookie: true** to the fb.init(); function. Thanks for help!!!

Comment: if my answer is relevant will you please accept it?

Comment: Saving variables globally didn't fix the error but still it's a nice workaround/way to keep the values of variables unchanged at page refresh. I really appreciate your help & time spent! Thx!